# MinGW-w64 can't find Makefile that exists

Tags: windows, makefile, build, cmake, mingw

I'm encountering an error in building one of my ExternalProjects:

> ```
> mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
> ```

Here is the [relevant code](https://github.com/syb0rg/Khronos/blob/master/cmake/Win32-ExternalProjects.txt) used to build it within my project:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(sphinxbase)
if (${SPHINXBASE_FOUND})
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SPHINXBASE_INCLUDE_DIR}/sphinxbase/)
else ()
    ExternalProject_Add(
        sphinxbase
        GIT_REPOSITORY      "https://github.com/syb0rg/sphinxbase.git"
        #GIT_SHALLOW         TRUE
        SOURCE_DIR          ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/sphinxbase
        UPDATE_COMMAND      ""
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND   ""
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE     ON
        LOG_DOWNLOAD        ON
        LOG_UPDATE          ON
        LOG_CONFIGURE       ON
        LOG_BUILD           ON
        LOG_TEST            ON
        LOG_INSTALL         ON
    )
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(sphinxbase SOURCE_DIR)
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(sphinxbase BINARY_DIR)
    SET(SPHINXBASE_SOURCE_DIR ${SOURCE_DIR})
    SET(SPHINXBASE_BINARY_DIR ${BINARY_DIR})
    SET(SPHINXBASE_LIBRARIES ${SPHINXBASE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/Debug/x64/sphinxbase.lib)
    SET(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} sphinxbase)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SPHINXBASE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/win32)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SPHINXBASE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
endif ()
SET(LIBS ${LIBS} ${SPHINXBASE_LIBRARIES})
```

`${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` is set correctly to `C:/Users/syb0rg/Dropbox/Development/Khronos/Khronos/build`, and here is what part of the folder looks like:

[image]

As you can see, I have a Makefile present at the specified location.  What's going on here?  Why can't CMake/MinGW find it?

---

**Supplemental build information, [link to full project](https://github.com/syb0rg/Khronos)**

My program's configure log:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- No build type selected, default to Release
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find sphinxbase (missing:  SPHINXBASE_LIBRARY SPHINXBASE_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find pocketsphinx (missing:  POCKETSPHINX_LIBRARY POCKETSPHINX_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find LibSndFile (missing:  LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARY LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find tritium (missing:  TRITIUM_LIBRARY TRITIUM_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Any missing dependencies will be downloaded upon running "make"
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/syb0rg/Dropbox/Development/Khronos/Khronos/build
```

And build log:

```
[  2%] Performing build step for 'PortAudio'
-- PortAudio build command succeeded.  See also C:/Users/syb0rg/Dropbox/Development/Khronos/Khronos/build/build-data/src/PortAudio-stamp/PortAudio-build-*.log
[  4%] No install step for 'PortAudio'
[  6%] Completed 'PortAudio'
[ 17%] Built target PortAudio
Scanning dependencies of target sphinxbase
[ 20%] Creating directories for 'sphinxbase'
[ 22%] Performing download step (git clone) for 'sphinxbase'
-- sphinxbase download command succeeded.  See also C:/Users/syb0rg/Dropbox/Development/Khronos/Khronos/build/build-data/src/sphinxbase-stamp/sphinxbase-download-*.log
[ 24%] No patch step for 'sphinxbase'
[ 26%] No update step for 'sphinxbase'
[ 28%] No configure step for 'sphinxbase'
[ 31%] Performing build step for 'sphinxbase'
CMakeFiles\sphinxbase.dir\build.make:110: recipe for target 'build-data/src/sphinxbase-stamp/sphinxbase-build' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:103: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/sphinxbase.dir/all' failed
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Comment: At least some make file was found: `Makefile:82:...`

Comment: @alk Yes, is also finds the Makefiles for Portaudio, which is [built using the same build procedure/file hierarchy](https://github.com/syb0rg/PortAudio2)

Comment: How do you get this `Makefile`? The repo you use doesn't contain it: `Makefile` will be created after configuration, but you have configuration step disabled.

Comment: @Tsyvarev CMake generates it automatically

Answer (score -3):

Stop using MinGW.

MinGW has not been updated [since 2013](//sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files). It has been replaced by Cygwin and
MSYS2. The MinGW project doesn’t even offer a [64-bit compiler](//sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/History).

Cygwin can be installed in about [3 minutes](//serverfault.com/a/409076), I would give it a try.

Comment: I am using MinGW-w64, which is still an unkept project today.  This information is present both in my question and on the project  installation instructions